# When running a virtualized operating system on my Mac, is it important to have anti virus software?

Tags: virtualization, anti-virus

Just curious if it is important to have anti virus for a virtualized operating system I got to thinking, that operating system is actively connecting to the Internet, so I thought maybe it had vulnerabilities.

Comment: What OS are you virtualizing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are virtualizing a version of Windows, I would recommend you *do* use anti-virus software. Although Windows is running in a VM, it still *is* Windows and is vulnerable to viruses. A good choice of anti-virus software for Windows is [Microsoft Security Essentials,](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/security-essentials) which is free from Microsoft. (Note that: "Your PC must run genuine Windows to install Microsoft Security Essentials.")

If you are virtualizing a Linux distro, there is [malware for Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware), so I would recommend anti-virus as well. There are several listed on [the Linux malware Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware#Anti-virus_applications), including [Avast!](http://www.avast.com/en-us/index) (Free) and [AVG](http://free.avg.com/us-en/homepage) (Free).

Comment: @Jerrod I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows in a VM and it has Internet access, then yes, you should consider running anti-malware software.

VMs attempt to be as much like real computers as possible, so Windows in a VM is just as vulnerable as Windows running on real hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is important to protect a VM from malware and exploits, it might not be quite as important for VMs where you can easily take a snapshot of a clean system and revert to that snapshot periodically (every day, every user logout, after every time going online, after browsing, etc.)  Also, the VM might be running on a system that has an active firewall and suspicious activity logging external to the VM (for example: Little Snitch on a Mac can warn you if a VM attempts to connect to some unexpected port number).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should run anti-virus software on a VM, and also on your Mac standalone. Macs are vulnerable to viruses, and Virtual Machines can posse a risk to your Mac because it is emulating a virtual environment. I've gotten my fair share of viruses running Crossover for Counter Strike. So if your going to use a VM I highly recommended using one!

You can never be to safe these days...